# Do we know what The Bendu is?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

[The Bendu](http://starwarsrebels.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bendu) is a self-proclaimed neutral force user that appears in Rebels.  The only information on him appears to be from wikia sites.  From new canon, do we know who or what he is, exactly?

Comment: gone, for now, thank goodness

Comment: He is the one in the middle.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Hey!

Comment: He's the Bendu. As he often says.

Comment: He's a Time Lord who went to the wrong Universe and discovered how to use the Force!  (He's voiced by Tom Baker - the 4th Doctor - couldn't resist.)

Comment: Bendu, or Bendu-Not. There is no Ben-Try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, his species isn't currently known.

[image]